# Intellij: File > Open Recent > Manage Projects... > Open in SAME window

Tags: intellij-idea

I have these settings:

[image]

When I go to

```
File > Open Recent > {choose one of the recent projects}
```

Then the chosen project opens in the same window, perfect!

**But** when I go to

```
File > Open Recent > Manage Projects... > {choose one of the projects from the popped dialog}
```

this project will be opened in a **second instance**.

Is this some kind of intellij bug? Can I fix/adjust this?

Alternative: Can I make the list in the first approach "richer" regarding the information displayed? Like in the popping dialog, I want to see parts of the path, for which I see "ah, it's projectX in branchY" or "ah, thats the projectX's trunk". This is the only reason why I go through the "Manage Projects..." menu in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there are a few issues against IntelliJ related to this confusion:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-159138#tab=Linked%20Issues

You could upvote those and - for some near term mitigation - perhaps you could name your projects such that the additional context you want ("ah, it's projectX in branchY" or "ah, thats the projectX's trunk") is present in the project name?

The goal being to enable you to choose correctly from `File > Open Recent > {choose one of the recent projects}` and you wouldn't need to fall back to `File > Open Recent > Manage Projects...`.

You can rename a project from the `File > Project Structure` dialog ... as long as it is a folder-based project (`.idea`) rather than file based Project (`.iws`).

Comment: I wasn't aware of the renaming feature - works like a charm! Also, I upvoted the linked issue, thanks for finding this, superb!